# Remove part of string after equals sign

Tags: tcl

I would like to ask for help with removing part of the string.
Input string : `var1=dog,var2=home`

What I would like to get as the result is :
Output string : `var1=dog,var2=`

So idea is to cut end of string till first equal sign.
 I was trying some possibility like trim but no good results.

Comment: Please do post your attempt next time. You can refer to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You could find the index of the last `=`, and take the substring ending there:

```
set str "var1=dog,var2=home"
set new [string range $str 0 [string last = $str]]
puts $new
```

```
var1=dog,var2=
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably

```
set input var1=dog,var2=home
regexp {.*=} $input output
```

That is, match the longest prefix sequence of characters that ends with an equals sign, and store it in the variable `output`.

Another way:

```
set output [string range $input 0 [string last = $input]]
```

Get all characters in `$input` from the first character up to (and including) the last equals sign found in the string.

```
set output [string trimright $input ehmo]
```

would actually work for this exact example (I scrambled the characters to stress that trim doesn't cut by string but by character).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a plain regsub:

```
set x "var1=dog,var2=home"
regsub -all {\=[a-z]+$} $x "=" x
puts $x
```